# Detect pressed key when flutter desktop app is not focus or minimise

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I want to detect keyboard event and for that I am using [RawKeyboardListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html)/[RawKeyboard](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/RawKeyboard-class.html). This is working when app is focused, but when app is minimised or unfocused RawKeyboard listener isn't working anymore.

As per flutter documentation regarding [Background processes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes) I tried isolate and place RawKeyboard listener there but I didn't get expected behaviour.

I have tried below methods of RawKeyboard,

```
RawKeyboard.instance.keysPressed
```

and

```
RawKeyboard.instance.addListener((value) {
   print(value);
});
```

and also send this value to isolation port but didn't get any luck when app is unfocused or minimised.

Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Not yet. Still trying to figure out the solution